# torch7: Filtering out NaN values

Tags: lua, nan, torch

Given any general `float torch.Tensor`, possibly containing some **NaN** values, I am looking for an efficient method to either replace all the NaN values in it with zero, or remove them altogether and filter out the "useful" values in another new Tensor.

I am aware that a trivial way to do this is to manually iterate through all the values in the given tensor (and correspondingly replace them with zero or reject them for the new tensor).

Is there some pre-defined Torch function or a combination of functions which can achieve this more efficiently in terms of performance, which relies on the inherent CPU-GPU optimisations of Torch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it looks like there is no function in `torch` checking tensor for NaNs. But since NaN != NaN, there's a work around:

```
a = torch.rand(4, 5)
a[2][3] = tonumber('nan')
nan_mask = a:ne(a)
notnan_mask = a:eq(a)

print(a)
 0.2434  0.1731  0.3440  0.3340  0.0519
 0.0932  0.4067  nan     0.1827  0.5945
 0.3020  0.1035  0.5415  0.3329  0.7881
 0.6108  0.9498  0.0406  0.9335  0.3582
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x5]

print(nan_mask)
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
[torch.ByteTensor of size 4x5]
```

Having these masks, you can efficiently extract NaN/not NaN values and replace them with whatever you want:

```
print(a[notnan_mask])
...
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 19]

a[nan_mask] = 42
print(a)
  0.2434   0.1731   0.3440   0.3340   0.0519
  0.0932   0.4067  42.0000   0.1827   0.5945
  0.3020   0.1035   0.5415   0.3329   0.7881
  0.6108   0.9498   0.0406   0.9335   0.3582
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x5]
```

Comment: Alexander, thanks. And on doing some more googling online, I found the following solution, similar to yours, which achieves what I wanted in just one line: `ws[ws:ne(ws)] = 0`, where, **ws** is the tensor of weights.

Comment: @AdarshChauhan, this is exactly the same solution.